# EAS build (cloud not local): SDK version issue - This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

I'm building a React-native application with eas build in the cloud.

The app uses

- Expo 46.0.17
- React-Native 0.69.6

And I get a warning from Apple saying I don't target iOS 16.1

```
ITMS-90725: SDK version issue - This app was built with the iOS 15.5 SDK. Starting April 25, 2023, all iOS and iPadOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later.
```

I checked expo.dev and it's using Xcode 13.4 to build the app.

How can I configure EAS to use at least Xcode 14.1?

Comment: if you can try upgrade your expo project to 47 or 48

Comment: No, upgrading to expo 47 should do the trick, I'll let you know tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to expo 47 makes EAS build with Xcode 14.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`expo update 48`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the correct ios image in eas.json, in my case I hadn't defined it so I specified:

```
"production": {
  "ios": {
    "image": "default", //this line, read the first refernced article
    "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
  }
}
```

References:

READ IT [1]: https://expo.dev/changelog/2023/09-28-new-xcode-ios

 [2]: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/infrastructure/